# How to get a SUM of all parameters in the single column of database

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get a SUM off all numerical entries in one of the tables of my DB

```
id | parameter
--------------
1  | 5
2  | 1
3  | 11
4  | 3
```

My php is:

```
    $total = 'SELECT parameter FROM resource_table';
    $res = $db->prepare($total);
    $res->execute();
    while($row4 = $res->fetch()) {
        $count_sum1[$row4['parameter']][] = $row4;
    }
        $count_sum = array_sum( $count_sum1 );

print<<<END
$count_sum
END;
```

this is not working, as I can guess I am not doing something correctly.

Please help

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Have you tried using or know of MySQL's aggregate `SUM()` function instead? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/ - Column must be an `int` in order for it to work properly.

Comment: The column is int and I am trying to do this now, will keep you posted, thanks for suggestion

Comment: You're welcome. However, it's always nice to pinpoint the actual problem with your original code.

Comment: All worked fine and I will take your suggestion about pinpointing the problem next time I am here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the database do the work:

```
SELECT SUM(parameter) FROM resource_table
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot, I will accept your answer as soon as I can. All works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to stick to php:

```
<?php
    // code
    while($row=$res->fetch())
        $count_sum+=row["parameter"];
    // code
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, database engine supports simple operations, such as SUM(), AVG(), MIN() and lot of others... so actually you are able to do some basic operation on the specific engine. Read a documentation to your database engine, because you could use MySql, MSSQL, or plenty of others and every use its own type of functions.

But I suppose that you use MySQL, so the function is simply SUM():

```
SELECT SUM(parameter) FROM tableName;
```